# Shift+Key in two keystrokes

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard

Is there any way to use the shift key in the following manner: 'click' the shift key, and then click the key to be shifted?

Of course I can use the caps-lock key, but then I would have to click it again to stop it. I want the 'shifting' to be for only the following keystroke.

(Can it be done using the Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator?)

Comment: You mean you want to press and release the shift key and have the shift hold until another key is pressed?

Comment: @CharlieRB Yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press the shift key 5 times in a row, semi fast.

It will bring up a dialog box asking if you want to activate sticky keys.

If you choose to do so, that will allow you to press the shift key and release it, but keep it active until you type whatever keystroke after that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention "clicking" the keys, I am going to recommend using the on-screen keyboard that is built into windows. The on-screen keyboard behaves exactly as you have just described.

Comment: +1. Not what I'm looking for, but it fits the bill.